# Django reverse URL issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm having issues getting the following code *(below)* to work *(there are no errors)* . In my template I'm outputting `item.get_settings_url`  but I get nothing. What I'm I doing wrong here?

**In my models I have the following model method:**

```
def get_settings_url(self):
        return reverse('sms.views.keyword_settings', args=[str(self.keyword)])
```

**urls:**

```
 url(r'^keyword/^(?P<keyword>[\.\w-]+)/settings/$', views.keyword_settings, name='keyword_settings')
```

**view:**

```
def keyword_settings(request, keyword):
    return render_to_response('keyword_settings.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: does your view indeed say `pass` or is that just an example ?

Comment: yes I just pass for now? why could this be the issue?

Comment: yes.. this is the issue. You are not sending back the context .

Comment: ok I added render_to_response I will update the example, but still get the same i.e. blank

Comment: you need to send the object in the context - `return render_to_response('keyword_settings.html', {'item': item} context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: No sorry I'm not being clear item is being rendered in another view correctly, and when outputting item.get_settings_url it is blank. all other item.name etc work and show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL contains a named parameter. Hence, you need to pass that name when calling `reverse`. Also, you should use the `name` of the URL to make the reverse lookup short and easier to maintain:

```
return reverse('keyword_settings', kwargs={'keyword': str(self.keyword)})
```